# User password is not hashed when creating through Django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I have inherited the user class to make custom authentication. I do not get password hashing this way. It just stores as plain text in MySQL database. I have created staff through admin panel and unable to login as staff. Furthermore I have also created auth API endpoints using DRF and Djoser and am unable to login with the user profiles created through Django admin panel.

Here is my code.

[models.py](https://models.py/)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

[admin.py](https://admin.py/)

```
from .models import User

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I have seen old replies in Stack Overflow suggesting changing the parent class to `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin` . When I try this the add user template form only has 3 fields. Username, Password and Password Confirmation.

[admin.py](https://admin.py/)

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DefaultUserAdmin
from .models import User

class UserAdmin(DefaultUserAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

How do I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a custom UserAdmin as well so i guess i can help you a little bit with that

try this one:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    """Define admin model for custom User model with no email field."""

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
```

And i also think that there`s problems in your models.py bcs you dont have userManager

UserManager uses when you`re creating user so i guess problem in that